# Faster and more efficient alternative for Tunnelblick

Tags: network, vpn

I have to use Tunnelblick (VPN) to be able to connect to a server, the problem is that Tunnelblick is very buggy and laggy and sometimes also causes wierd problems like overheating when the laptop is folded (it does not shut off). Or frequent crashes.

Now I was wondering if there was a better alternative for doing so.

Kind regards,

Robbert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently switched from Tunnelblick to [Viscosity](https://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/). Awesome, never gives me that laggy trouble, but it requires a license.

A pretty good free option is [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) but I have had login issues with it sometimes. Once you're logged in it's solid though.

Comment: Both are just GUI wrappers for openvpn, so inherently they are the same